# get the file path with Python on Windows error

Tags: python, filepath

I want to load the file path with Python,on my Windows.
but now there is a problem:
the code:

```
def Test2(rootDir):
    f = []
    for lists in os.listdir(rootDir): 
        path = os.path.join(rootDir, lists) 
        #print (path)
        #img = cv2.imread(path,0)
        #cv2.imshow("image",img)
        if os.path.isdir(path): 
            Test2(path)
        if os.path.isfile(path): 
            print (path)
```

> `Test2("D:/111test/picpic")`

and the consequence is :

```
D:/111test/picpic\haha1\111.png
```

the consequence is not I want,because it contains '/'&'\'.
How to resolve this problem?

**Anothor problem**:
I got the file path successfully by using Test2("D:\111test\picpic");

```
D:\111test\picpic\haha1\111.png
```

and now I want to replace these filepath into a list,the code I use:

```
if os.path.isfile(path): 
        print (path)
        f.append(path)
        print(f)
```

and the consequence is what I don't want:

```
['D:\\111test\\picpic\\haha1\\111.png', 
 'D:\\111test\\picpic\\haha1\\222.png']
```

because the filepath of the list contains double"\".What should I do?

My wish:get the filepaths,and place them in a list correctly.
I am appraiciate for your method!!!

I'm glad for your answer!

Comment: add your code to post as a text instead of picture

Comment: okay.have done it .Please help me.

Comment: That is because you are specifying a directory separator as `/` whereas it is \ on your os (windows). Try calling the function like `Test2("D:\\111test\\picpic")`

Comment: @shahkalpesh thank you .This problem is resolved.But now I want to place these file path in a list.I use this code:
            f.append(path)
            print(f)
and the consequence is :['D:\\111test\\picpic\\haha1\\111.png', 'D:\\111test\\picpic\\haha1\\222.png'].How to resolve this ?

Comment: If you only want the files, and not the directories, you can use `os.walk()` instead to get the directories and file separate instead of the extra test.

Comment: What is the problem with `['D:\\111test\\picpic\\haha1\\111.png', 'D:\\111test\\picpic\\haha1\\222.png']`? Please elaborate extra problems in the original post and include what result you would like to obtain

Comment: @Maarten Fabré I got the file path successfully.And now I want to place the filepath to a list so that I can get the filepath by the list.There is the problem:how can I do this place these file path into a list

Comment: @Maarten Fabré  I edited the new problem.Please help me.Thank you much!

Comment: But why is this difference between `\\` and `/` important?

Comment: I don't know why

Comment: then why is is what you don't want?

Comment: there are double"\",it's not a filepath.I want get:D:\111test\picpic\haha1\111.png instead of D:\\111test\\picpic\\haha1\\111.png

Comment: Windows explorer accepts paths with '\\' just fine. Else you will need to do a string.replace('\\', '/')

Comment: nope.I got the filepath(D:\111test\picpic\haha1\111.png) successfully.and i place them to a list.and then I print the list.Why it changde to double"\".This is my problem.

Comment: that is because python uses `\` as an escape character for special characters in strings, so a single \ needs to be escaped by a \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should switch to using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) when you're dealing with Windows paths. If you're on Python 2, it's available as a [package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib/) too.

To give you an example how to use the pathlib library:

```
def Test2(rootDir):
    f = []
    rootDir = pathlib.Path(rootDir)
    for iter_file in rootDir.iterdir(): 
        if iter_file.is_dir(): 
            Test2(iter_file)
        if iter_file.is_file(): 
            print(iter_file)
```